# How can i calculate result from two function on Javascript?

Tags: javascript

so im a rookie. And wanna ask why i cant calculate the result from two functions?
I want to save value from quantitiy on banyak() function.
And i have the formula to calculate form which is to get input width,height,length (its a volume rectangular prism)
The result is... Result +Nan.. I want result from banyak() is number so i can calculate with the result from mult().
can anyone help me?
and by the way this is just testing code..

```
    function banyak(value){
   var qty = value;
  return qty;
   var cobaQty= document.getElementById('cobaQty');
   cobaQty.textContent=qty;
       }
       
       
function mult(pj,lb,tg){
          var isipj=pj;
          var isilb=lb;
          var isitg=tg;
          var hasil=isipj*isilb*isitg;
        
      
        //declare variable untuk panjang B1 dan lebar B1
        var vb1 = 0.4;
        var pb1 = parseFloat(pj)+parseFloat(vb1);
        var lb1 = parseFloat(lb)+parseFloat(vb1);

        //declare variable untuk panjang B2 dan lebar B2
        var vb2 = 0.7;
        var pb2 = parseFloat(pb1) + parseFloat(vb2);
        var lb2 = parseFloat(lb1)+parseFloat(vb2);


        //RUMUS B1
        var rumuspjb1= (parseFloat(tg)*2) + parseFloat(pb1);  
        var rumuslbb1= (parseFloat(tg)*2) + parseFloat(lb1);
 
        //RUMUS B2
        var rumuspjb2= (parseFloat(tg)*2) + parseFloat(pb2);  
        var rumuslbb2= (parseFloat(tg)*2) + parseFloat(lb2);
        
        //Mendapatkan perbandingan B1
        var panjangplanoB = 75;
        var lebarplanoB = 65;
        var b1p1 = parseFloat(panjangplanoB) / parseFloat(rumuspjb1);
        var b1p2 = parseFloat(lebarplanoB) / parseFloat(rumuspjb1);
        var b1lb1 = parseFloat(panjangplanoB) / parseFloat(rumuslbb1);
        var b1lb2 = parseFloat(lebarplanoB) / parseFloat(rumuslbb1);

        //Mendapatkan perbandingan B2
        var b2p1 = parseFloat(panjangplanoB) / parseFloat(rumuspjb2);
        var b2p2 = parseFloat(lebarplanoB) / parseFloat(rumuspjb2);
        var b2lb1 = parseFloat(panjangplanoB) / parseFloat(rumuslbb2);
        var b2lb2 = parseFloat(lebarplanoB) / parseFloat(rumuslbb2);  

        //Mendapatkan hasil B1
        var B1 = b1p1;
          if (B1 < b1p2){     
          var B1 = b1p2;
          }
          if (B1 < b1lb1){     
          var B1 = b1lb1;
          }
          if (B1 < b1lb2){     
          var B1 = b1lb2;
          }

          B1 = Math.ceil(B1); //Ini untuk pembulatan. B1 Plano Nanti dikali Rp10000..


        //Mendapatkan hasil B2
        var B2 = b2p1;
        if (B2 < b2p2){     
          var B2 = b2p2;
          }
          if (B2 < b2lb1){     
          var B2 = b2lb1;
          }
          if (B2 < b2lb2){     
          var B2 = b2lb2;
          }

          B2 = Math.ceil(B2); //B2 Plano

          //Mendapatkan rumus C1
          var rumusc1p = ((parseFloat(tg) * 4) + 3) + parseFloat(pb1);
          var rumusc1l = ((parseFloat(tg) * 4) + 3) + parseFloat(lb1);
          
          //Mendapatkan rumus C2
          var rumusc2p = ((parseFloat(tg) * 4) + 3) + parseFloat(pb2);
          var rumusc2l = ((parseFloat(tg) * 4) + 3) + parseFloat(lb2);
          
          //Mendapatkan perbandingan C1
          var panjangplanoC = 109;
          var lebarplanoC = 79;
          var c1p1 = parseFloat(panjangplanoC) / parseFloat(rumusc1p);
          var c1p2 = parseFloat(lebarplanoC) / parseFloat(rumusc1p);
          var c1lb1 = parseFloat(panjangplanoC) / parseFloat(rumusc1l);
          var c1lb2 = parseFloat(lebarplanoC) / parseFloat(rumusc1l);
          
          //Mendapatkan perbandingan C2
          var c2p1 = parseFloat(panjangplanoC) / parseFloat(rumusc2p); 
          var c2p2 = parseFloat(lebarplanoC) / parseFloat(rumusc2p);
          var c2lb1 = parseFloat(panjangplanoC) / parseFloat(rumusc2l);
          var c2lb2 = parseFloat(lebarplanoC) / parseFloat(rumusc2l); 
          
          //Mendapatkan C1
          var C1 = c1p1; 

            if (C1 < c1p2){     
              var C1 = c1p2;
            }          
            if (C1 < c1lb1){     
              var C1 = c1lb1;
            }
            if (C1 < c1lb2){     
              var C1 = c1lb2;
            }
 
          C1 = Math.ceil(C1); //Ini untuk pembulatan. C1 Plano Nanti dikali Rp10000..
          
          //Mendapatkan C2
          var C2 = c2p1;
          if (C2 < c2p2){     
          var C2 = c2p2;
          }
          if (C2 < c2lb1){     
          var C2 = c2lb1;
          }
          if (C2 < c2lb2){     
          var C2 = c2lb2;
          }

          C2 = Math.ceil(C2); //Hasil C2

          ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          //////////////Menghitung biaya bahan dasarnya///////////////////
          ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          var hargaplanoB=10000;
          var ongkos=7500;
          var hargaplanoC=20000;
          var hargatotalBCO;
          var sumB1 = hargaplanoB / B1;
          var sumB2 = hargaplanoB / B2;
          var sumC1 = hargaplanoC / C1;
          var sumC2 = hargaplanoC / C2;
          var hargatotalBCO = parseFloat(sumB1) + parseFloat(sumB2) + parseFloat(sumC1) + parseFloat(sumC2) + parseFloat(ongkos);  
          hargatotalBCO = Math.ceil(hargatotalBCO);
          var banyakqty=banyak();

          document.getElementById('rupiah').value = 'Rp. '+hargatotalBCO+(+banyak());
    }
```

here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcft3d0n/)

Comment: Have you traced the flow of your code carefully? Try to see how `mult()` is calling `banyak()`? What is the expected arguments for `banyak()`? How is the arguments used?

Comment: In `fun banyak(value)` you have code after `return qty` that will never get executed. put them above `return qty`

Comment: I very strongly recommend first cleaning up your code. Focus on good variable names, good indentation and general code style. Very often this process leads to an answer.